# Why can't I center Markdown image syntax with p tag but div works?

Tags: html, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a GitHub flavored `.md` file and I have been trying to center a couple of images with the `p` tag. It doesn't work but when I switch it to a `div`, it works as expected. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/Petesta/2ad5b126669435dab13c1ae964793468) what it looks like.

```
<p align="center">
  
  ![Python](https://img.shields.io/badge/Python-fff?logo=python)
  ![Ruby](https://img.shields.io/badge/Ruby-fff?logo=ruby)
  
</p>

<div align="center">
  
  ![Python](https://img.shields.io/badge/Python-fff?logo=python)
  ![Ruby](https://img.shields.io/badge/Ruby-fff?logo=ruby)
  
</div>
```

If I don't mix Markdown with HTML and do it this way, it works. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/Petesta/2ad5b126669435dab13c1ae964793468?permalink_comment_id=4046831#gistcomment-4046831) what it looks like.

```
<p align="center">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Python-fff?logo=python" alt="Python" />
  </a>
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Ruby-fff?logo=ruby" alt="Ruby" />
  </a>
</p>
```

The only difference I see between these two ways, is that the first code block doesn't embed the images into the `p` tag, but is a sibling of it. Is there a way to get the first way to work with `p` tags or is it not possible that way?

Comment: Note that [the `align` attribute has been obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for many years.

Answer (score 2):

The empty lines in your code *already* insert `<p>` tags, and since `<p>` cannot be nested, that means that the implicit `<p>` (without alignment) will force-close the previous `<p>` that had the alignment, i.e. the first snippet will end up with something like this in the DOM:

```html
<p align="center"></p>
<p>
  <a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
  <a href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
</p>
```

...as you can see when you look at the output on GitHub in your DevTools:

[image: screenshot]

That is because this...

```markdown
A

B
```

...will be rendered as this:

```html
<p>
  A
</p>
<p>
  B
</p>
```

However, just removing the empty lines won't work either, because then the block is identified as an HTML tag with immediate content which won't be parsed. It does work if you then use `<img>` tags manually as well instead of relying on Markdown syntax for the content (as you already noticed).

With `<div>` it works because a `<p>` *can* be within a `<div>` and the `<div>`'s alignment will still have effect:

[image: screenshot]